# Pandas, Glob, use wildcard to stand for end of filename

Tags: pandas, glob

I am programming (Pandas) around a problem where certain generated files are saved with a date attached to the file. For example: `file-name_20220814.csv`.

However, these files change each time they are generated, creating a new ending to the file. What is the best way to use a wildcard to stand for these file date endings?

Glob? How would I do that in the following code:

`df1 = pd.read_csv('files/file-name_20220816.csv')`

Comment: if you know there should only be one match: `pd.read_csv(glob.glob('files/file-name_*.csv')[0])` otherwise this just uses the first matching path

Comment: From glob, `import glob; p_list = glob.glob('files/file-name_*.csv');` how would you deal with multiple matches? If "just read them all", then `df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(i) for i in p_list)`

Comment: @mitoRibo: I have been trying exactly that, with no joy. But I just tried `pd.read_csv(glob('files/file-name_*.csv')[0])` and it works. (glob vs glob.glob)

Comment: You're probably importing with `from glob import glob` rather than just `import glob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @mitoRibo:

`pd.read_csv(glob('files/file-name_*csv')[0])`